# При скачивании файла он скачивается повреждённым

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Нажимаю на ссылку по которой скачивается файл excel, а он скачивается повреждённым.

Ссылка для скачивания

```
<a type="blob" class="link-example-download" href="../assets/files-examples/sravnenie-1-v-1.xls" download="Сравнение_1_в_1_ПРИМЕР.xls">Пример файла</a>
```

Ошибка при открытии файла:

[image: Ошибка при открытии файла]

Comment: Где сам метод контроллера который который отвечает за это самое скачивание, Боюсь без дополнительной информации мы вам не сможем ответить что не так с вашим кодом. Пожалуйста дополните вопрос !

Comment: Странно, в коде скачивается файл .xls а открывается xlsx